# Redirection after AJAX callback not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am working with codeigniter function code which is being called by a jquery ajax function:

```
case "Set":

    var message = $('#message').val()
    if ((searchIDs).length > 0) {
        alert("searchIDs " + searchIDs);
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Ajax/update",
                data: {
                    i: searchIDs,
                    m: message
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function() {
                    alert("OK");
                }
            })
            .done(function() {
                alert("OK");
                location.href = "my_controller/detail";
            });

    } else {
        alert("nothing checked")
    }
    break;
```

I am not getting any errors in firebug or in the response from the called php function also seen in firebug. However I don't think the .done function is working because I don't see the OK alert and the page refresh is not happening.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why do you have both a `success` and a `done`?  You don't need the former if you have the latter.  When you debug in Firebug, what is the server's response to the AJAX request?  The code doesn't seem to handle error responses in any way.

Comment: you want tot add an `error:` parameter, it's possible you aren't catching server errors.

Comment: I'm trying to follow the second answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632701/refreshing-a-page-with-codeigniter-after-ajax-click-event. I'm not experienced in ajax. David the code is working properly and I am getting "200 OK 120ms" in firebug. The only thing not working is the page refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the oncomplete event handler?  e.g.

```
$.ajax({
   ...
   success: function(){
       ...
   },
   complete: function() {
       //when complete
       ...
   }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Just as follow up I'm trying to follow the second answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632701/refreshing-a-page-with-codeigniter-after-ajax-click-event. Is the answer there wrong? - Bill